# Add a class to <li> if sub menu exist using mysqli query

Tags: php

I want to know, how do i add a class to a `<li>` if it has a sub_menu?

I have a proper HTML menu populated from mysql database.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/about-us/">About us</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap framework, so for the drop down menu i have to replace my `<li>` to this:

```
<li class='dropdown'>
    <a aria-expanded='false' aria-haspopup='true' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='/about-us/' role='button'>
        About us <span class='caret'></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to know how do i check if the `<li>` has any sub_menu before running a sub menu query in the loop? so that i can add markup for dropdown menu.

**Here's the PHP Code that generates MENU:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php
                    $res1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM primary_nav ORDER BY m_menu_id ASC");
                    while($menu=$res1->fetch_array())
                    {
                    ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $domain; ?><?php echo $menu['m_menu_link']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $menu['m_menu_name']; ?>
                </a>
                <?php
                    $res1_pro=$connection->query("SELECT * FROM primary_subnav WHERE m_menu_id=".$menu['m_menu_id']." ORDER BY seq ASC");
                    //echo "\xA";
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($res1_pro) > 0) {
                    echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' ."\xA";
                        while ($pro1_row = $res1_pro->fetch_array()) {
                    ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $domain; ?><?php echo $pro1_row['s_menu_link']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $pro1_row['s_menu_name']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                        }
                    echo '</ul>' ."\xA";
                    }
                    ?>
            </li>
            <?php
                        echo "\xA";
                    }
                    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I could do thi with the jQuery, but i want to do it the HTML way.

Comment: Do it the HTML way? Do you mean you want to do it when you output the HTML from PHP?

Comment: yes exactly.... i dont want to use jQuery, i want PHP to add the drop down class and other markup.

Comment: You would wait to output the parent `<li>` (the one you want the class on) until you have checked for the sub-menu in your `if` statement.

Comment: yes, i thought the same. it has to be checked in the `if` statement but i am confused how to put a check without running the sub query in the loop...

Comment: You're not running the sub-query until you check if `$res1_pro` has more than 0 rows.

Comment: ok, but the query runs after i have defined the `<li>` Where do i put the if condition?

Comment: why not use ul li ul li {} in CSS?

Comment: @Gianmarco i am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `<li>` with the class in the `if` check for the number of rows. Then you have to add an `else` clause to echo out the `<li>` without the class:

```
<?php
$res1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM primary_nav ORDER BY m_menu_id ASC");
while($menu=$res1->fetch_array())
{

    $res1_pro=$connection->query("SELECT * FROM primary_subnav WHERE m_menu_id=".$menu['m_menu_id']." ORDER BY seq ASC");
    //echo "\xA";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res1_pro) > 0) { // echo the list element with the class here
?>
        <li class="foo">
            <a href="<?php echo $domain; ?><?php echo $menu['m_menu_link']; ?>"><?php echo $menu['m_menu_name']; ?></a>
<?php
    echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' ."\xA";
    while ($pro1_row = $res1_pro->fetch_array()) {
?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $domain; ?><?php echo $pro1_row['s_menu_link']; ?>"><?php echo $pro1_row['s_menu_name']; ?></a>
        </li>
<?php
    }
    echo '</ul>' ."\xA";
    } else { // echo the normal list element if number of rows is 0 
?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $domain; ?><?php echo $menu['m_menu_link']; ?>"><?php echo $menu['m_menu_name']; ?></a>
<?php    
    }
?>
</li>
<?php
 echo "\xA";
}
?>
```

***Note***: This particular coding style makes it very hard to write and maintain code should the need arise. You may want to look into ways to combine PHP and HTML to make it easier to update and maintain your code.

Comment: i got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file`

Comment: I cleaned it up @XeBii

Comment: thanks a million. As you can see with my code, i am just a beginner and coding with my small understanding of PHP. i am learning things, whenever i got stucked i came here for help. because i am learning on my own. i hope i will be a good coder/developer in future and will follow the proper coding standards. your help means alot to me. many many thanks :)